# Saving variables from a BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Good day there!

I am making an app which are to react on a received SMS. When a SMS in received it will tell another method what number it came from, and the content. The other method are to print this out.

The problem is that the BroadcastReceiver class has to be static (if I understand it correct) which makes it impossible for me to save variables or send it to other methods.. Been Googling for a couple of hours.. Tried SharedPreferances! How should I move forward?

Pieces of code:

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();

        if (intentAction.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();


                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + phoneNumber + "; message: " + message);


                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ phoneNumber + ", message: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

            } 
        }

}
```

}

Comment: No, BroadcastReceiver do not need to be static, and what do you mean by saying "a class has to be static"? Have you registered the BroadcastReceiver with a proper IntentFilter? Have you got the permission to access SMS?

Comment: Everytime I tried to access public variables from the class which extended the BroadcastReceiver it said I could because the class was static, and couldn't interact with non-static content. 
But I managed to get it working by doing setting up a IntentFilter in the onCreate() method! Which looks like this: 

SmsBroadcastReceiver broadCastReceiver = new SmsBroadcastReceiver();
this.registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));

And now it works:D